# The SSL connection could not be established see inner exception

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate

I am running a program to connect to a data service and extract data. The Program creates excels. I am getting the below error while it tries to establish connection with the Source.

Message=The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

Inner Exception 1:
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotTimeValid

Any way to bypass these certificate issues, when Iam able to loging to the front end in Firefox why cudnt I run the API.

Comment: The exception means that the SSL certificate expired on the source side.

Comment: You've got a couple of options. 1) Disable certificate validation - not advised. 2) Get the certificate on the remote service fixed (probably out of your control)

Comment: @phuzi as a temporary fix could you please help me with the 1st solution that you have proposed ? Steps could you share ?

Comment: There are multiple questions and answer discussing this. It will probably depend on how you are attempting to connect to the remote service - code needed.